# Deploying Azure Cloud Service on a Hosted Cloud (not Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, paas, iaas, azure-role-environment

I am developing a cloud application deployed on an Azure Cloud Service and I want to deploy it now on another hosting provider provides only a VM.

Is there a way that I install the Azure run-time on Windows VM and it works as an Azure Role without changing the code?

I read about Azure Stack but seems it is not in production yet so I cannot use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that I install the Azure run-time on Windows VM and it
>   works as an Azure Role without changing the code?

AFAIK, No it's not possible to do so. While it is true that an `Azure Cloud Service` runs in a VM only but that's just tip of the iceberg. There's much going on behind the scenes which makes the `Azure Cloud Service` scalable and PaaSy (if that's the correct word :)). Worth mentioning there is the Fabric Controller which manages the lifecycle of the VMs running your cloud services.

> I read about Azure Stack but seems it is not in production yet so I
>   cannot use it.

Apart from not being in production, I don't think Azure Stack supports Cloud Services today.